# how exactly code.org lost data with 32-bit index? Suppose they use MySQL database

Tags: mysql, index, backup, mariadb

Today the headline [The 32-Bit Dog Ate 16 Million Kids' CS Homework](https://news.slashdot.org/story/17/01/22/1940249/the-32-bit-dog-ate-16-million-kids-cs-homework). Quote from [blog.code.org](http://blog.code.org/post/156133016748/this-mornings-technical-difficulties-on-code)

> The way we store student coding activity is in a table that until
>   today had a 32-bit index. What this means is that the database table
>   could only store 4 billion rows of coding activity information. We
>   didn’t realize we were running up to the limit, and the table got
>   full. We have now made a new student activity table that is storing
>   progress by students. With the new table, we are switching to a 64-bit
>   index which will hold up to 18 quintillion rows of information. On the
>   plus side, this new table will be able to store student coding
>   information for millions of years. On the down side, until we’ve moved
>   everything over to the new table, some students’ code from before
>   today may temporarily not appear, so please be patient with us as we
>   fix it.

We now suppose the use MariaDB/MySQL. Can you explain me in detail (with SQL statements and error messages) this issue? I don't understand this data loss very well.

Comment: Morale of this story:  Check for errors after running SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By `index`, he actually means key column. The maximum value MySQL can store in a signed `INT` column is 2147483647 ([documentation link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)), which is stored in 32 bits (4 bytes, 2 to the power of 32).

Their problem would have occurred when the table reached 2147483647 rows (and less if there are gaps) - any subsequent `INSERT`s would fail, and the data would be lost.

It's easy to reproduce what's happened:

Create a test table with a `INT` primary key:

```
mysql> create table incfail 
       ( 
          pk INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
       );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Set the primary key value to be nearly the maximum value:

```
mysql> alter table incfail AUTO_INCREMENT= 2147483646;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

`INSERT` a few values:

```
mysql> insert into incfail values (NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into incfail values (NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from incfail;
+------------+
| pk         |
+------------+
| 2147483646 |
| 2147483647 |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

The primary key is now at its maximum value, and the next `INSERT` will fail:

```
mysql> insert into incfail values (NULL);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'
mysql>
```

The data was lost:

```
mysql> select * from incfail;
+------------+
| pk         |
+------------+
| 2147483646 |
| 2147483647 |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: MySQL supports unsigned integer types, and these are commonly seen in auto increment columns in the wild. `INT UNSIGNED` is limited to 2^32 - 1 or 4,294,967,295.

Answer (score 3):

This is the relevant part:

> "Any student progress from 9:19 to 10:33 a.m. on Friday was not
>   saved..." explained the embarrassed CTO of the educational non-profit
>   Code.org, "and unfortunately cannot be recovered."

For a short period all inserts have failed since no new entries could have been added to the table due to the technical limitation.

---

The other part

> "On the down side, until we've moved everything over to the new table,
>   some students' code from before today may temporarily not appear, so
>   please be patient with us as we fix it."

Is talking about a **temporarily** unavailability of some of the data, since it is being moved from the old table to the new table, probably in chunks.

---

I'm guessing the issue was caused by declaring AUTO_INCREMENT with INT that was changed in the new table to BIGINT.

Comment: See updated answer (bottom)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that they changed from `INT` (which defaults to `SIGNED`) to `INT UNSIGNED`.  This would increase the limit from 2 billion to 4 billion.  However, the wording implied that they started with `INT UNSIGNED` and are moving to `BIGINT UNSIGNED`.

Another issue -- do they really have 2 billion rows?  In some situations, ids are "burned", thereby leading to hitting the 2B limit without really having that many rows.  This can happen from many operations:

- `DELETE` + `INSERT`
- `REPLACE`
- `INSERT IGNORE`
- and some others

In the first two cases, first a row is deleted, thereby throwing away an `id`; then the insert occurs, creating a new id.

In the `INSERT` cases, the processing pre-allocates the ids, but then fails to use them.

A deliberate way to mess with ids is to insert a row with a higher id.  Subsequent inserts always go from the highest current value.

I wonder where the data comes from...  If it is manual data entry, I am having trouble imagining how long it would take to enter 4 billion records!